# How can I run a Cygwin command (not a Windows native command) as privileged?

Tags: windows, bash, cygwin, cron, uac

If I open a (elevated via UAC) *Bash Shell* in *CygWin*:

```
Luis@Kenobi /cygdrive/c/Windows/system32
$ crontab.exe -l -u Luisito
must be privileged to use -u
```

Tested on WinXP-SP3 and Win7-SP1. Same results on remote (SSH) console.
Both accounts (*Luis* and *Luisito*) belong to *Administrators*.

How can I use, for example, **crontab** to list another user's crontab list?

Additional Points:

- Tested with user **SYSTEM**:

I have this file named MyShell.cmd:

```
c:\CygWin\bin\bash.exe --login -i
```

So I call it from (elevated by UAC, of course) **PSExec** to get *System* rights:

```
psexec -i -s d:\MyShell.cmd
```

and I get a new shell to try, but the problem keeps:

```
SYSTEM@Kenobi /cygdrive/c/Windows/system32
$ whoami.exe
SYSTEM

SYSTEM@Kenobi /cygdrive/c/Windows/system32
$ crontab.exe -l -u Luisito
must be privileged to use -u
```

Answer (score 1):

If the situation has not changed (and things like these don't seem to have, really) then according to [this post](http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2003-02/msg00469.html):

> The -u option only works for SYSTEM so far and as such is somewhat useless
>   on Cygwin currently.

Seems the only way to get `-u` working is to run the shell under the `SYSTEM` user, a "normal" elevated Administrators shell does not suffice.

Comment: No, it doesn't work either, @Adrian Frühwirth. I have edited the original question to show the results using PSExec to get System privileges.